# Google Spreadsheet query in a row which matches criteria

Tags: jquery, select, google-sheets, where-clause

In [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YWEtVGIO2T-Ra1MLk3KsUy9AqMfkG4Pd6bvAi6tZ91c/edit#gid=0) in C2 a user picks a name of a person and the whole row (Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8) needs to be auto-filled from another database sheet, called Database, within this spreadsheet, depending on what the user has selected in cell C2. In C2 the data validated from that very same database.

```
=QUERY((Database!A2:H13)," select Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8 where Col3='C2'")
```

The error I get is, *Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col4*

Comment: Could you please provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on (free of sensitive information), clearly indicating what is the desired outcome?

Comment: Added to the original description.

Comment: I see you could find a solution already, right? The spreadsheet you shared contains the formula `=QUERY({Database!$A$2:$H$13},"Select Col4, Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8 where Col3='" & C2 & "'",0)`, which achieves your purpose. In this case, would you consider posting an answer explaining how you came up with this solution?

Answer (score 2):

The answers are laid out [via the link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YWEtVGIO2T-Ra1MLk3KsUy9AqMfkG4Pd6bvAi6tZ91c/edit#gid=0).
There are 3 ways to do this. I used the query method since VLOOKUP only allows data to be imported. If there is any new data not in the database and a user types it in all the VLOOKUP removes the data.

PS. In my particular case, which is not seen in the link, I had to use single quotes for sheet name and semicolon, not comma to divide formula into sections. So anyone having Parsing errors, might as well just try

```
=QUERY('Database'!$A$2:$H$13;"Select D,E,F,G,H where C='" & C3 & "'";0)
```

For VLOOKUP I had to use backward slashes, instead of commas, and semicolons -

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2:C;'Database'!C2:H;{2\3\4\5\6};0)))
```

I thank Google Docs Editors for providing me with the solution. [The thread can be found here](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/80539478?hl=en).